# Hardness of an optimization problem when some variables are fixed

Tags: computational-complexity, combinatorial-optimization, np

Given a general optimization problem, I would like to know what we can say about the hardness of the problem when a subset of its variables are fixed.

With the two (related) examples, it is clear that (1) it is possible to have an easy problem which remains easy when some of its variables are fixed, and (2), it is possible to have a hard problem which becomes easy when some of its variables are fixed.

1. In the Low-Rank Approximation problem, given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and a natural $r<\min(m,n)$, we want to find $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times r}$ and $V\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$ solving $$\min_{U, V} \|A-UV\|_F^2.$$

   - This problem can be solved in polynomial time (by using the SVD for example).
   - If the entries of $U$ are given, the following subproblem
     can also be solved in polynomial time, as it is a convex problem $$\min_{V} \|A-UV\|_F^2.$$
2. In the Nonnegative Matrix Factorization problem, given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and a natural $r<\min(m,n)$, we want to find nonnegative $U \in {\mathbb{R}}^{m\times r}$ and nonnegative $V\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$ solving $$\min_{U\geq 0, V\geq 0} \|A-UV\|_F^2.$$

   - This problem is hard to solve (proved by [Vavasis](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/070709967)).
   - If the entries of $U$ are given, the following subproblem
     can be solved in polynomial time, as it is a convex problem $$\min_{V\geq 0} \|A-UV\|_F^2.$$

My question is:

> **Is it possible to have an optimization problem solvable in polynomial time which becomes hard when some of its variables are fixed to specific values?**

It is maybe obvious that a problem remains hard when we know that this problem is hard when some variables are fixed to specific values, but I do not see how to show it.

I am interesed in any (counter-)example (combinatorial problem, graph problem, etc.). Thanks!